# How to convert this XML to CSV

Tags: csv, xml-parsing

Past 4 days I am trying to convert this XML file to CSV with this fields distribution

XML file part

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<ponudba podjetje="SO d.o.o." velja_od="23.09.2012 @ 12:30:48">
    <artikel koda="LS593EAR" naziv="HP ENVY 17-2199e" kategorija="Prenosniki" podkategorija="Hewlett Packard (HP)" v_akciji="ne" kosovnost="več">
    <opis>
    HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
    </opis>
    <opis_detail>
    HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)<br/><table> <col width="25%" /> <col /> <tbody> <tr> <th>Procesor</th> <td>Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM / 2.00 GHz / Quad-Core</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Delovni pomnilnik</th> <td>8 GB DDR3</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Trdi disk</th> <td>1 TB (1000 GB) / 5400 / SATA</td> </tr> <tr> <th>LCD zaslon</th> <td>43,9 cm (17,3'') Full HD HP Ultra BrightView Infinity Display (1920x1080)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Grafična kartica</th> <td>AMD Radeon™ HD 6850 Graphics</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Optična enota</th> <td>SuperMulti DVD-RW Double Layer</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 2.0</th> <td>2x</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 3.0</th> <td>1x</td> </tr>    <tr> <th>eSATA</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>HDMI</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WiFi</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Bluetooth</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WWAN</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Spletna kamera</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Card Reader</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Express Card</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>TV kartica</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Finger Print</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Vhodne naprave</th> <td>brez</td> </tr>     <tr> <th>Operacijski sistem</th> <td>Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Država uvoza</th> <td>Italijanska tipkovnica (priložene SLO nalepke)</td> </tr>  <tr> <th>Stanje modela</th> <td>HP Renew</td> </tr>     </tbody> </table>
    </opis_detail>
    <garancija_v_mesecih>12</garancija_v_mesecih>
    <cena_v_EUR>1.049,00</cena_v_EUR>
    <proizvajalec>HP</proizvajalec>
    <stanje>na zalogi</stanje>
    <url_foto_artikla>
    http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/0/c02034964.jpg.hri_4.jpg
    </url_foto_artikla>
    <vec_fotk_artikla>
    <slika href="http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/c/0/c02034982.jpg.hri_4.jpg"/>
    <slika href="http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/c/0/c02034991.jpg.hri_4.jpg"/>
    </vec_fotk_artikla>
    <teza_artikla_v_kg>2.9000</teza_artikla_v_kg>
    </artikel>
```

And this is CSV file I want to have - header all fields all data from XML not just some data:(

```
<!-- language: lang-csv -->

koda    naziv   kategorija  podkategorija   v_akciji    kosovnost   opis    opis_detail garancija_v_mesecih cena_v_EUR  proizvajalec    stanje  password    url_foto_artikla    vec_fotk_artikla
```

I tried this:

```
// The order here determines the order in the output CSV file
$columns = array(
    'koda',
    'naziv',
    'kategorija',
    'podkategorija',
    'v_akciji',
    'kosovnost'
);

// This will be used later on to correctly sort in the attribute values
// Note: the third paramter of "array_fill" determines what value to use
// in case a node lacks an attribute
$csv_blueprint = array_combine(
    $columns,
    array_fill(0, count($columns), '')
);

$data = array($columns);
$filexml = 'so_feed.xml';

if ( !file_exists($filexml) ) {
    // Do some error routine
} else {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
    $artikel = $xml->artikel;

    if ( !count($artikel) ) {
        // Stop processing 'cause there's nothing to do
    } else {
        foreach ( $artikel as $item ) {
            // Clone the row blueprint to leave the original unspoiled
            $row = $csv_blueprint;
```

Also I tried this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
//$artikel = $xml->artikel;
$ponudbas = $xml->ponudba;
...
    foreach ( $ponudbas as $ponudba ) {
        // Clone the row blueprint to leave the original unspoiled
        $row = $csv_blueprint;
```

But both scenarios does not parse all data from XML.
I dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

if you XML is exactly as you have copied it is not a valid XML document. It is missing the `</ponudba>` at the end.

Another thing to consider is the XML format are the data inside the elements, in your case we can see the use of double quotes '' in two elements (17''). This in some special cases can cause parsing errors. If you really want to use those, maybe is better to use the data inside CDATA Blocks to escape those special chars.

**Edit:** I have just saw that your XML contains HTML elements inside XML elements, you are encouraged to use CDATA blocks for that kind of XML elements.

If is easier to you, you can simply convert the XML to JSON and decode it directly to a php object:

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

If you want to write back a csv file, you should consider using fputcsv (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php)

**EDIT 2**
Try a simple test:

use:

```
$file='file.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($xml->artikel as $art)
{    
    echo $art->opis_detail;
}
```

This will output only:

```
HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
```

Now, if you use on your XML on the  node a CDATA element:

```
<opis_detail><![CDATA[HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)<br/><table> <col width="25%" /> <col /> <tbody> <tr> <th>Procesor</th> <td>Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM / 2.00 GHz / Quad-Core</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Delovni pomnilnik</th> <td>8 GB DDR3</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Trdi disk</th> <td>1 TB (1000 GB) / 5400 / SATA</td> </tr> <tr> <th>LCD zaslon</th> <td>43,9 cm (17,3'') Full HD HP Ultra BrightView Infinity Display (1920x1080)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Grafična kartica</th> <td>AMD Radeon™ HD 6850 Graphics</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Optična enota</th> <td>SuperMulti DVD-RW Double Layer</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 2.0</th> <td>2x</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 3.0</th> <td>1x</td> </tr>    <tr> <th>eSATA</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>HDMI</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WiFi</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Bluetooth</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WWAN</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Spletna kamera</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Card Reader</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Express Card</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>TV kartica</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Finger Print</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Vhodne naprave</th> <td>brez</td> </tr>     <tr> <th>Operacijski sistem</th> <td>Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Država uvoza</th> <td>Italijanska tipkovnica (priložene SLO nalepke)</td> </tr>  <tr> <th>Stanje modela</th> <td>HP Renew</td> </tr>     </tbody> </table>]]>
    </opis_detail>
```

This will now output:

```
HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
Procesor    IntelÂ® Coreâ„¢ i7-2630QM / 2.00 GHz / Quad-Core
Delovni pomnilnik   8 GB DDR3
Trdi disk   1 TB (1000 GB) / 5400 / SATA
LCD zaslon  43,9 cm (17,3'') Full HD HP Ultra BrightView Infinity Display (1920x1080)
GrafiÄna kartica    AMD Radeonâ„¢ HD 6850 Graphics
OptiÄna enota   SuperMulti DVD-RW Double Layer
USB 2.0 2x
USB 3.0 1x
eSATA   da
HDMI    da
WiFi    da
Bluetooth   da
WWAN    ne
Spletna kamera  da
Card Reader da
Express Card    ne
TV kartica  ne
Finger Print    ne
Vhodne naprave  brez
Operacijski sistem  Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
DrÅ¾ava uvoza   Italijanska tipkovnica (priloÅ¾ene SLO nalepke)
Stanje modela   HP Renew
```

I think this is the missing data no?

Comment: I forgot to put </ponudba>, my fault, sorry. Could you give me some json example, just to see what you talking about. Sorry, i am novice in PHP